# kubectl bind mount a volume like docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a docker image which I run it as below in my local mac:

1) creating filesystem -->
mkdir data & 
mkdir license

2)Docker Run : ---> 
docker run \
   --rm \
   -u `id -u`:`id -g` \
   -p 11225:11225 \
   -p 9090:9090 \
   -v `pwd`/data:/data \
   -v `pwd`/license:/license \

Now, I would like to run this in Kubernetes. While I expose the ports as service , How can I create the folders (data and license) and then expose that as bind volume in kubernetes cluster ? sample yml or kubectl command helps

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can find explanation of kubernetes Volumes in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/ which is what you really need to look into and decide which volume type is best for your particular case/environment.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/ is a good reading further to expand your understanding of persistent storage management in kubernetes with PVC/PV concepts.

Comment: Thanks . It talks about deploying a persistent volumes but not sure how to create folders on top of it. In some scenarios it expects the filePath to be available but my requirement is to have a folder created on the deployed node.

Comment: `hostPath` volume is the one that uses nodes local storage, but it is in most cases a solution that can be used on dev, but when you go prod and have multiple nodes/pods using hostPat volume may cause some serious issues (think about pod rescheduling to different node or 2+ pods scheduled on the same one)

Comment: yes..agree, in that case it is prone to fail..but one of the third party container expects the name of the folder to be same..thats where I end up facing this issue..but as of now, is there an option to have the Mountpath similar to hostpath , where I would like to create folder in the PV with the same name